# Why won't my radio group won't validate as required

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, radio-button

I'm using Angular 1.3.5 and have a radio group containing two radio buttons. They share the same `age` model. I want the group to be required and to display an error if one of them is not selected by the user. One requirement is that both options must be unchecked by default, so I can't pre-select an option.

I'm using the `ng-required="!age"` trick to validate, but the `contestForm.age.$error.required` error state never seems to be triggered. The `form__errors` UL is displaying on `contestForm.$submitted`, but not the actual LI for the required error.

**Jade**

```
li.form__field-group
    .form__field
        input#contest-age-of-majority(type='radio', value='ageOfMajority', ng-model='age', ng-required='!age')
    .form__field
        input#contest-parental-consent(type='radio', value='parentalConsent', ng-model='age', ng-required='!age')

    ul.form__errors(ng-show='contestForm.$submitted || contestForm.age.$touched')
        li.form__error(ng-show='contestForm.age.$error.required', translate='error.required')
```

Here's a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/EsLHmbEtMjDN38DDwHQU?p=preview

Comment: can you put together a plunker?

Comment: @SoluableNonagon I've added a plunker demonstrating this

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the form and the ng-model are separate entities; A model named `age` does not mean the form will have a field by the same name. Instead, the form relies on the name attribute of fields. I hadn't given the radios a name because several examples made it seem unnecessary because of the model.

I checked the generated source and Angular automatically names any unnamed fields with a number such as `name="108"` and `name="110"`. They would appear under these keys on the form object, not as an `age` field.

It seems obvious now, but the solution was to give a `name="age"` attribute to both radio buttons. Now the validation works and the required error displays if the form is submitted while no option is selected.

```
li.form__field-group
    .form__field
        input#contest-age-of-majority(type='radio', name='age', value='ageOfMajority', ng-model='age', ng-required='!age')
    .form__field
        input#contest-parental-consent(type='radio', name='age', value='parentalConsent', ng-model='age', ng-required='!age')

    ul.form__errors(ng-show='contestForm.$submitted || contestForm.age.$touched')
        li.form__error(ng-show='contestForm.age.$error.required', translate='error.required')
```